# Where can I see what Color properties in .NET like "BlanchedAlmond" look like?

Tags: .net, colors

I'm in the middle of writing code in .Net to draw something in my app and I need to pick a color to use. But what does the color "Chartreuse" look like? Isn't there a nice bitmap that shows what each of the system colors look like somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [site](http://www.blizzardskies.com/bz/colorchart.html).

This site is nice because it shows how the color will look as foreground and background color.

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN - Colors by Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358802(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/7cb36a7b-3731-48f6-b91b-1d8c503f140e/What-are-the-aspnet-Named-Colors.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a site: http://adonnart.free.fr/gratuit/140coulu.htm

with Hex-Codes

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_color_tryit.asp?color=BlanchedAlmond

(Pay attention the URL and modify as necessary)